# django message when logout

Tags: django

Once an user logged out of the site, it should redirect to the home page and to display the message as "U are successfully logged out" in the top of the page. Anyone help me in displaying message in home page?

Comment: Try changing `settings.MESSAGE_STORAGE` to `'django.contrib.messages.storage.cookie.CookieStorage'`, does that help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using sessions. Can be simpler.

In the logout view, set an entry in the session variable, like `session['just_logged_out'] = True`, and in the home page view, check for the variable.

```
try:
  just_logged_out = request.session.get('just_logged_out',False)
except:
  just_logged_out = False
```

In the template, you can use

```
{% if just_logged_out %}  You are successfully logged out {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 12):

You could use the user_logged_out signal combined with the messages framework:

First, make sure the messages framework is set up (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/).

Then include this code somewhere that will be called (I tend to put it in a receivers.py module and then import it from a models.py file in an installed app):

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib import messages


@receiver(user_logged_out)
def on_user_logged_out(sender, request, **kwargs):
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Logged out.')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me with Django 2.2.10. The message is added to the user who has just logged out, so it won't pop out on the anonymous LOGOUT_REDIRECT page

Answer (score 7):

give a try to:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

class YourCustomLogoutView(LogoutView):

    def get_next_page(self):
        next_page = super(YourCustomLogoutView, self).get_next_page()
        messages.add_message(
            self.request, messages.SUCCESS,
            'You successfully log out!'
        )
        return next_page
```

in urls:

```
url(r'^logout/$', YourCustomLogoutView.as_view(), {'next_page': settings.LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL}, name='logout'),
```

Comment: I read the source and arrived at the same solution. But the method name `get_next_page` now does more than what the name implies. I wish we could override another method instead of `get_next_page`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the messages framework.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: I tried the code messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.') after post save. But message is not displaying

Comment: You'll need to add code to display the message in your template. Read the docs in the link I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplified version of the answer from @andilabs:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView

class UserLogoutView(LogoutView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.info(request, "You have successfully logged out.")
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And in your urls.py:

```
path('logout/', views.UserLogoutView.as_view(), name='logout')
```

Answer (score 0):

"get_next_page()" in LogoutView is [depricated](https://groups.google.com/g/django-updates/c/_5K8ECZF7ug)

I ended up using "get_success_url()":

```
class CustomLogoutView(LogoutView):
  def get_success_url(self):
    success_url = super(CustomLogoutView, self).get_success_url()
    messages.add_message(
      self.request, messages.SUCCESS,
      'You have successfully logged out!'
    )
    return success_url
```