# django message not displaying after logout

Tags: django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [django message when logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393929/django-message-when-logout)

Once an user logged out of the site, it should redirect to the home page and to display the message as "U are successfully logged out" in the top. 
Iam using from django.contrib.auth import logout as auth_logout for logout and my logout views as

```
@secure_required
def signout(request):
    auth_logout(request)
    messages.success(request, ("You r successfully logged out"), fail_silently=True)
    return redirect('/')
```

Anyone help me in displaying message in home page?

Answer (score 2):

**What have you tried?**

You can use the messages framework for such purpose, please try understanding or rephrasing a specific question before posting broad questions

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Answer (score 0):

Checkout django messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

In your view:

```
def contact(request):
    if request.POST:
        messages.success(request, 'Success!')
     return render_to_response (...)
```

Comment: Its working. But i need this once i logout. But msg is not displaying once i logged out

Comment: But iam having one more views which is similar to the one what u posted above,in that instead of render_to_response, i used redirect('/'), its working. Its displaying msg in the redirected page.The logout msg only not displaying

Comment: Does home have the `messages` template?

Comment: yes i put the message template as {% if messages %}
  <div align='center'>
   <ul id="message" >
       {% for message in messages %}
        <ul{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{message}}</ul>
       {% endfor %}
   </ul></div>
 {% endif %}

Comment: In the link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393929/django-message-when-logout, i found the answer